# Change serverTrustPolicy of Alamofire.SessionManager to still use top-level convenience methods like Alamofire.request

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire

I use Alamofire for networking in many classes like: UserApi, EpayApi, DeliveryApi etc. And everywhere my requests look like that:

```
Alamofire
            .request(MyRouter.login(login, password))
            .responseJSON { response in
                //    
        }
```

The problem is that our SSL Certificate has expired on server - this is only temporary, however I want to make Alamofire allow call requests even with invalid certificates.

I found the following answer here at stackoverflow:

```
static var manager : SessionManager = {

// Create the server trust policies
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
    "my server url": .disableEvaluation
]

// Create custom manager
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
    configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
)

return manager
}()
```

This snippet of code works perfectly, but the problem is that I have to use new SessionManager instead of Alamofire singleton in every classes. Is there any way to globally change Alamofire's serverTrustPolicyManager?

Using Alamofire v4.3.0 and Swift v3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create class and call it "NetManager" with static var of type SessionManager in it.

```
class NetManager {

    static var manager : SessionManager = {

    // Create the server trust policies
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "my server url": .disableEvaluation
    ]

    // Create custom manager
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )

    return manager
    }()

}
```

Then use it like this:

```
NetManager.manager
    .request(MyRouter.login())
    .responseJSON { response in
    //
}
```